# Weird behaviour of Java List

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt

I have this requirement to show the amount with thousand separator. I have this POJO class with these two methods which I call according to my requirements

```
public Integer getTotalAmount() {
    return totalAmount;
}

public String getTotalAmountWithSeparator() {
    return String.format("%,d", totalAmount);
}

public void setTotalAmount(Integer totalAmount) {
    this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
}
```

now when I use this method *getTotalAmountWithSeparator()* in my another class which looks like this and I do a println to see if the amount is being shown properly(which it does).

```
List<SupplierOrderDetails> list = SupplierOrderDetailBussinessLogic.getInstance().getSupplierOrderDetailsFromsupplierOrder(supplierOrder);

      DataProviderBuilder dpb = new DataProviderBuilder();

    // add heading data
    dpb.add("so", supplierOrder.getSupplierOrderNo());
    dpb.add("sn", supplierOrder.getSupplier().getPerName());
    dpb.add("sec", supplierOrder.getSection().getAlternateName());
    dpb.add("od", supplierOrder.getSupplierOrderCreated().toString());

    // add table data
    dpb.addJavaObject(list, "data");
```

here is the actual method *getSupplierOrderDetailsFromsupplierOrder(supplierOrder);* which gets the data from the db.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<SupplierOrderDetails> getSupplierOrderDetailsFromsupplierOrder(SupplierOrder supplierOrderDetails){
    Session hibernateSession = HibernateUtills.getInstance().getHibernateSession();
    Criteria criteria = hibernateSession.createCriteria(SupplierOrderDetails.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("supplierOrderID", supplierOrderDetails));
    List<SupplierOrderDetails> models = criteria.list();

    System.out.println(" models.size()     " + models.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < models.size(); i++)
    {
        if (models.get(i).getId() != null)
        {
            models.get(i).getProductID().getProductCode();
            models.get(i).getProductID().getBrandName();
            models.get(i).getPurchasePrice();
            models.get(i).getOrderQty();
            models.get(i).getTotalAmountWithSeparator();
            System.out.println(models.get(i).getProductID().getBrandName() + "  TotalAmount      " + models.get(i).getTotalAmountWithSeparator());

        }
        // System.out.println(models.get(i).getPurchasePrice());
    }
    return models;
}
```

but when I do a println of the list data here,it does not show the separator in the amount why?????what am I doing wrong

```
dp = getSupplierOrderData(Long.parseLong(supplierOrderId));
System.out.println("DATA    "+dp.getString("data"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because dp.toString() method uses getTotalAmount() and not getTotalAmountWithSeparator()

Comment: thanks for your comments. Can you explain why it uses getTotalAmount() and not the other method.

Comment: without seeing the toString() method, I just can't guess why